# Google Sheets Query with importrange by date range

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Trying this Formula:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18r5cARjmlRsbb0VRaAS6kAMkJm1p2qe0LsPCtYLS1xA/edit?resourcekey#gid=561906440","Form Responses 1!A:X"),"select col1,col4,col5,col6,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15 where Col2 > date ‘2021-06-27’ and Col2 < date ‘2021-07-31'",0)`

and getting:
`Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "Col2 "" at line 1, column 80. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...`

Can't figure it out for my life.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to address this if you had granted access to your sheet via a link. However, for starters, you have curly single quotes in the following snippet where straight single quotes are required:

`where Col2 > date ‘2021-06-27’ and Col2 < date ‘2021-07-31'`

To be specific, the single quotes front and back of your first date, and front of your second date, are curly where they need to be straight, i.e.:

`where Col2 > date '2021-06-27' and Col2 < date '2021-07-31'`

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to share link going forward. I did figure this out using: =Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18r5cARjmlRsbb0VRaAS6kAMkJm1p2qe0LsPCtYLS1xA/edit#gid=55252520","Form Responses 1!A:X"),"select Col2,Col5,Col6,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16 where Col2 >=date '"&TEXT(A4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 <=date '"&TEXT(B4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") I ended up linking the Dates to cells. Makes it easier for upkeep